# Android MDM, Add email accounts in native email app from code, force PIN-code, set APN and auto join WiFi

Tags: android, mdm

I'm working on a MDM solution for iPhone and Android.
The iPhone part is done and is working great:)

On the android part there are a couple of things left.
I have never used an Android phone before, so its kinda new for me.

First of is how to add an email account (exchange, gmail and IMAP).
And if I understand it correct there are a couple of different native mail apps that are bundle with different versions of android and phone models.

I've tried to add an exchange account with

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
am.addAccount("my_exchange_mail@company.com", "com.htc.android.mail.eas", null, null, null, null, null);
```

But it does not show up in Settings -> Accounts & Sync.

Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Second thing is how to add APN settings to the phone.
What I understand is that google removed that ability in Ice cream sandwich, if that's correct then we don't want to add it to our MDM solution.

Third thing is how to force a user to add a PIN code (or password or the thing where you swipe of the 9 dots)
For now I set a a minimum length of the password and a password quality (to something)

```
mDPM.setPasswordMinimumLength(mAdminName, 4);
mDPM.setPasswordQuality(mAdminName, DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mDPM.setPasswordExpirationTimeout(mAdminName, 1);
}
```

Then I show the set new password intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This makes the set new password intent show and the user can select between PIN, password and the swipe-thingy. The option "No password" is disabled. But the user can use the back button on the phone to skip setting a new password.

Are there any way to really force the user to set a PIN?

Fourth thing is about auto joining a newly added WiFi.
I can add a WiFi with the following code. But is there any way to make the phone automatically connect to the WiFi when it is in range?

```
public boolean addWifi(String SSID, String encryptionType, String password, boolean hiddenNetowrk, boolean autoJoin) {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
    if (encryption.trim().equals("WEP")) {
        config.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + password + "\"";
        config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    } else if (encryption.trim().equals("WPA")) {
        config.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    config.hiddenSSID = hiddenNetwork;

    int id = wifi.addNetwork(config);
    wifi.enableNetwork(id, false);

    return true;
}
```

Well, that was a long question:) Hoping for some answer on some of the four problems:)